# Select query error in android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am trying to get values from database using `id`. But it cannot fetch any data, it gives me error for syntax.

Here is my select function

```
public Employee getStudentById(int Id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  " +
                Employee.KEY_ID + "," +
                Employee.KEY_name + "," +
                Employee.KEY_cast + "," +
                Employee.KEY_mobile +
                " FROM " + Employee.TABLE
                + " WHERE " +
                Employee.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string

        int iCount = 0;
        Employee student = new Employee();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                student.Employee_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Employee.KEY_ID));
                student.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Employee.KEY_name));
                student.cast = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Employee.KEY_cast));
                student.mobile = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Employee.KEY_mobile));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return student;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? And what is that error?

Comment: while compiling: SELECT id,name,cast,mobile FROM emp WHERE id=? in sqlite

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Rectify **STATEMENT** Here

**SYNTAX**

```
" WHERE " + Employee.KEY_ID + " = '"+ Id +"'";
```

You can try with

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  *  " FROM "+ Employee.TABLE + " WHERE " + Employee.KEY_ID + " = '"+ Id +"'";
```

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya .This answer solved my problem

Comment: I don't see what is the syntax problem this answer is solving. Rather it is changing the query for the worse by not using `?` parameters.

Comment: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters. it gives this error

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> while compiling: SELECT id,name,cast,mobile FROM emp WHERE id=?
> ```

`cast` is a [sqlite keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). You need to quote it in double quotes: `"cast"`. Or better yet, rename the column to something that is not a keyword.